# error al detectar java con flutter en version 2022.1 con windows

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter

[image: Imagen de refencia]

Tengo instalado la version 8 de java y también ya usé establecer la variable de entonrno JAVA_HOME

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como solucionarlo, creo que tengo que instalar una versión anterior de android studio pero no estoy seguro, o en todo caso podré usar de forma normal flutter en visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Si prestas atención es solo una advertencia. No pasa nada si no lo arreglas.

Incluso si no tuvieras Android Studio instalado te aparecería un mensaje como este:

> [!] Android Studio (not installed)

[Ejemplo encontrado en Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27283).

En tu caso parece haber encontrado una versión de Android Studio pero no la versión de Java que suele traer integrada. Si, Android Studio viene con su propia distribución de Java, OpenJDK.

No es lo mismo la instalación local de Java que la distribución incorporada con el IDE.

Supongo que lo hacen por evitar cuestiones legales a las que estarían sujetos si usaran el JDK de Oracle.